# Ember Array As Data Store

Tags: ember.js

Currently I have `App.Data.Files = []` as a simple data store for some of my Ember data. Currently don't see the need to load in Ember Data if the above array and some methods on the objects will be able to persist back what I need.

**Problem:**
I currently have a problem with bindings. When removing files objects from the array (using something like `App.Data.Files.pop()`), Ember doesn't update the properties/navigation view with the new values.

The file type controllers such as ImageController when re-rendered for `/images` have lost their files though.  Should I instead be using an `ArrayProxy`? Or should I be setting up a new controller for the original files and then controllers for each type as well?

**FileObj**

```
App.FileObj = Ember.Object.extend
  id: null
  filename: null
  type: null
  size: null
  url: null
  isImage: Ember.computed.match 'type', /image\/.*/
  isPDF: Ember.computed.match 'type', /application\/pdf/
  isOtherFile: (->
    return !this.get('isImage') && !this.get('isPDF')
  ).property('isImage','isPDF')
```

**Application Controller:**

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
  totalFileCount: (->
    return App.Data.Files.length
  ).property('@each')
  imageCount: (->
    return App.Data.Files.filterProperty('isImage').length
  ).property('@each')
```

**ImagesRoute**

```
App.ImagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', App.Data.Files.filterProperty('isImage'))
```

**Images Controller**

```
App.ImagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  content: []
  imageCount: Ember.computed.alias('length')
```

**View Snippet**

```
<!-- Left Hand Navigation -->
<div class="list-group">
  {{#link-to 'images' class='list-group-item'}}
    <span class="badge">{{imageCount}}</span>
    Images
  {{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'pdfs' class='list-group-item'}}
    <span class="badge">{{pdfCount}}</span>
    PDFs
  {{/link-to}}
  {{#link-to 'others' class='list-group-item'}}
    <span class="badge">{{otherCount}}</span>
    Others
  {{/link-to}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `App.Data.Files.pop()` doesn't trigger the bindings/observers needed to update your template, instead you should use `App.Data.Files.popObject()`.

You can see the introduced array methods in [Ember.MutableArray docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html)

You need also to update your computed property dependents keys to reflect what's being changed inside of them

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
  totalFileCount: (->
    return App.Data.Files.length
  ).property('App.Data.Files.length')
  imageCount: (->
    return App.Data.Files.filterProperty('isImage').length
  ).property('App.Data.Files.@each.isImage')
```

This is a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mekexoje/1/edit) with this running

Comment: Not sure why I didn't see those methods on the object while playing in console. Just did a test with `popObject()` and the counts in the view did not update.  Inside of ApplicationController, is there a different way I need to bind the properties?

Comment: @al3xnull I updated the answer, you need to change the dependent keys of `totalFileCount` and `imageCount` computed properties

Comment: Thanks a ton Marcio! =] Guess I didn't realize the string inside of the property call could be bound to pretty much anything.